# FEM stress analysis by considering bending moment

Tags: finite-element-method, solidmechanics

I found an [example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102522/stress-calculations-using-finite-elements/224021#224021) of using `FEM` for stress analysis in the forum, the code provided by @user21, which is very friendly for beginners.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

(*Physical Parameters*)
L = 1;
h = 0.1;
ss = 10;(*Shear stress on beam. This stress is applied to the boundary, and its direction seems to be upward rather than perpendicular to the centerline of the beam.*)

(*Finite element meshing*)
reg = Rectangle[{0, -h}, {L, h}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg];
materialParameters = {Y -> 10^3, ν -> 33/100};

(*Elasticity assumptions*)
ps = {Inactive[
      Div][({{-(Y/(1 - ν^2)), 
         0}, {0, -((Y (1 - ν))/(2 (1 - ν^2)))}}.Inactive[
         Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][({{0, -((Y ν)/(1 - ν^2))}, {-((Y (1 - ν))/(2 \
(1 - ν^2))), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}], 
   Inactive[
      Div][({{0, -((Y (1 - ν))/(2 (1 - ν^2)))}, {-((Y \
ν)/(1 - ν^2)), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] +
     Inactive[
      Div][({{-((Y (1 - ν))/(2 (1 - ν^2))), 
         0}, {0, -(Y/(1 - ν^2))}}.Inactive[Grad][
        v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}]};

(*Boundary condition And mechanical equilibrium equation calculation*)
{uif, vif} = 
  NDSolveValue[{ps == {0, NeumannValue[ss, x == L]}, 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0], 
     DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x == 0]} /. 
    materialParameters, {u, v}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];

(*Force-displacement visualization*) 
dmesh = ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uif, vif}, "ScalingFactor" -> 1];
Show[{mesh["Wireframe"], 
  dmesh["Wireframe"[
    "ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]}]
```

It calculated the displacement of the beam. Based on the linear elastic assumption, the beam should be able to undergo large deformation.

So how can I change the boundary conditions applied at the right endpoint so that the **direction of force is perpendicular to the centerline and achieve a bending moment effect** as shown in the figure below? I think modifying boundary condition `ps == {0, NeumannValue[ss, x == L]}` can achieve this, but after trying it out, it seems that we cannot adjust the direction of applied force here. Does this involve coordinate transformation? The direction of the applied moment torque will change with deformation(In a fixed coordinate system). But the stress in this code is upward along the y-axis. If the elastic body is compressible, it will be stretched very long but cannot show the effect of bending.

[image: DOI:10.13140/RG.2.2.23485.72168 The paper was found by Google Images.]

Here is another [example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111158/beam-deformation-due-to-localized-force-distribution) of adding distributed force on a certain interval, which is somewhat similar to my problem. Modifying the boundary conditions `{planeStrainOperator[10^3, 33/100] == {0, NeumannValue[-5., y == 1 && 2 <= x <= 3]}` in the example can solve this kind of problem.

I checked the official [documentation](https://www.wolfram.com/language/core-areas/fem/#get-started), but did not find how to incorporate this special stress requirement into finite element calculations. The purpose of studying this example is to consider dynamic problems in the future, that is, analyzing its motion under external forces. This requires solving partial differential equations with respect to time. Dynamic problems are more complex than stress analysis, but the FEM calculation process is similar.

Thank you for your comments and help!

Comment: @Nasser, thank you for your help in editing to increase the readability of the code. I forgot to use the `M.SE editor` plug-in, which led to a complex display in this code.

Comment: Please, add `Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]` in the beginning of the code. Also note, this is not beam you try to describe, this is plate.  The beam deformation model discussed for example on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250978/large-deformation-of-solids/251011#251011

Comment: @AlexTrounev Beams, plates, and shells are always confusing to me. Do you have any simple explanation to distinguish these concepts? Because the original post I read described Euler beams, so I took this example as a beam(I think the large deformation is based on the linear elastic assumption, it is OK to modify the `ps` equation in code, so I don't pay much attention to this aspect.). I'll go read the post you gave me and see if I misunderstood it. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Ben basically with a shell or plate its thickness is much less that other dimensions (width, length). This is not the case with beam. As for difference between plate and shell, I had to google this as I forget myself also. Google says **in the unstressed state, the shell structure has curvature as opposed to the plates structure which is flat**

Comment: @Nasser Yes. Intuitively, it looks like this. Plates are flat, two-dimensional structural elements with a uniform thickness that is small compared to their other two dimensions (length and width).  Shells are curved, three-dimensional structural elements with a uniform thickness that is small compared to their other dimensions. Beams are long, slender structural elements that primarily resist bending (flexural) loads. I'll look for the mathematical description in the textbook to make it clearer.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250978/large-deformation-of-solids)?

Comment: @user21 Thank you and Alex for your comments. I just missed this post by searching for the keyword `stress analysis`. It's very helpful. I'm learning it.

Comment: @Ben  Nonlinear dynamic of the Euler-Bernoulli beam see on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187448/dynamic-nonlinear-damped-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation